# Machine scheduling in matlab via integer linear programming

Tags: matlab, optimization, integer, scheduling, linear-programming

I am having difficulties implementing a simple machine scheduling problem in Matlab with the built-in (I)LP solver.

I am looking at the most simple case:
There are j jobs and m machines, all jobs have equal weights and no release dates. Each job needs to be assigned to a machine and the goal is to minimize the total completion time (sum of all production times of the jobs on a specific machine).

I want to find the optimal schedule via the intlinprog function. I know that Matlab cannot always find this optimal value, however I am curious in the way this is implemented.

The syntax of the intlinprog function in the optimization toolbox in Matlab is:

```
x = intlinprog(f,intcon,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

where f is the sum of the completion times. This value needs to be minimized.

What are the values I need to input for A, B, Aeq and beq? I assume that for the integer case, the intcon is 1:j (and [] for the non-integer version), the lb is

```
zeros(j,1)'
```

and the ub is

```
ones(j,1)'
```

Could someone please help me with the correct inputs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read [the documentation for `intlinprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html)? It [explains all of the input variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html#bts3f9f-2).

Comment: I have and I understand the input variables. However, I cannot relate them to this specific problem.

Comment: The approach that works best for me is to write down the mathematical model first. Then from this mathematical description populate the matrices needed by `intlinprog`. Note: unfortunately this last step is not always trivial.